# Javascript and editing value

Tags: javascript, html

When i try to edit "teksti" I cannot do it with the code below. My enviroment gives error all the time. In my excercise I should edit the "teksti" to another string. I am not able to get the code as text so I attached image instead.

[Picture of code in VIOPE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5E8B.png)

There is some kind of hint what could be used, but it also gives error:

```
<body>
    <p id="teksti">Muokkaa minua!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text into the question itself. Only form control elements have `value`. Use `innerHTML` or `textContent` to get/set the content of a `<p>` element.

Comment: It should be the format that is in the image. I cannot modify the bottom and top code, only code in the center..

Comment: Then you proceed by modifying the code in the center according to my comment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same thing you already have and assign the value to it like this:

```
document.getElementById("teksti").innerHTML = "JavaScript is easy"
```

You don't have `value` on `p` element.